# конфликт библиотек jquery и bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap4

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если подключаю jquery, cdn которого расположен на сайте bootstrap 4, у меня работает отслеживание события show.bs.modal, но не работает

```
     $(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0},700);
        return false;
     });
```

вылезает ошибка `$(...).animate is not a function` а когда я использую полный cdn jquery с их сайта, у меня отлично работает эта функция, но

```
     $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#mymodal', function(){
        console.log(1);
     });
```

не срабатывает. Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему подключением `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`